# cloneNode method doesn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to change the pictures places (put the 1 img where's the 2 img is, and vice-versa), and for this i'm trying to cloneNode the second img, but instead, it just bring me [object HTMLImageElement], even though it show the correct html  element in the console.log. What's wrong with my code ?

```
<div id="imgs">
<div id="img1">
<img src='../img/slide_1.jpg' class='slides-adm' id='teste1' onmousemove='drag(this);' />
</div>
<div id="img2">
<img src='../img/slide_2.jpg' class='slides-adm' id='teste2' onmousemove='drag(this);' />
</div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var id = obj.getAttribute('id');
    //console.log(id);

var img = document.getElementById(id);

    img.ondragstart = function(){
        return false;
    };

    function dropImage(e){
        img.removeAttribute('style');

        if(id == 'teste1'){
            img.style.top = e.clientY -300 + 'px';
            img.style.left = e.clientX -290 + 'px';
        }else if(id == 'teste2'){
            img.style.top = e.clientY -300 + 'px';
            img.style.left = e.clientX -540 + 'px';
        }else{
            img.style.top = e.clientY -300 + 'px';
            img.style.left = e.clientX -800 + 'px';
        }

        //console.log(img.style.left);
        if(img.style.left >= '230px' && img.style.left <= '250px'){
            var imgs = document.querySelector("#imgs").children;
            var imgId = document.querySelector("#img1");
            var imgCp = document.querySelector("#teste2");
            //here is my clone
            imgId.innerHTML = imgCp.cloneNode();

        }
    }

    function drop(e){
        dropImage(e);
        document.removeEventListener('mousemove' ,dropImage);
        document.removeEventListener('mouseup', drop);

            img.style.transition = 'all 500ms ease-in';
            img.style.left = '0px';
            img.style.top = '0px';
            imgs.removeAttribute('onmousemove');
    }

    img.addEventListener('mousedown', function(){
        document.addEventListener('mousemove', dropImage);
        document.addEventListener('mouseup', drop);
    });
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `imgCp.cloneNode().outerHTML` or `imgCp.cloneNode().innerHTML` to get actual html as string.

Answer (score 0):

You’re assigning `HTMLElement` to `innerHTML` property (which is string, so you’re getting `[HTMLImageElement]`). You should be appending it with `imgId.appendChild(imgCp.cloneNode())` instead.

Answer (score 0):

cloneNode as it's name says, clones a node in a new DOM element, what you're trying to do is set an element's innetHTML property with the cloned element...

What i would do is this:

```
var imgId = document.querySelector("#img1");
var imgCp = document.querySelector("#teste2");

var txtCP = imgCP.innerHTML;

imgId.innerHTML = txtCP;
```

you can check the documentation here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode